# What happens when object is destroyed when it is stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, linux, while-loop, destructor, infinite-loop

I want to know what would happen when destructor gets called on an object when the object is stuck in an infinite while loop in a different thread.

```
// Main thread creates the object
MyClass _obj = new MyClass():
// doing some stuff
delete _obj;
```

Where,

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
 // Start a thread which calls MyClass::MyPollingFn()
}

MyClass:: MyPollingFn()
{
  // runs in new child thread
  while(true)
  {
    // doing some work
    // sleep(5 seconds)
  }
}
```

Explanation:
There is a class object of MyClass which creates a thread and runs MyPollingFn method in an infinite loop. Every iteration of this method can change some class variables. Is it ok to destroy the object from parent thread which holds the object? Is there any possibility of this giving an issue?

Comment: Yes, it is 100% guaranteed to cause issues

Comment: Is it ok? Not if you want defined behavior. Don't destroy it until your thread has been terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `MyPollingFn` ever touches `this`, explicitly or implicitly (e.g. by accessing non-static member variables), then this code would exhibit undefined behavior, as `this` would become a dangling pointer.

And if it doesn't touch `this`, then why make it a non-static member function?

Comment: More precisely, the program's behavior is undefined if any access in the thread running `MyPollingFn` does not *happen-before* the `delete` in the other thread. There needs to be some explicit synchronization to avoid a data race.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible issues, including

1. Either you will try to join the thread in your destructor, in which case it will block.

---

**Edit**

i.e. if you add

```
MyClass::~MyClass()
{
  myThread.join();
}
```

and leave the `MyPollingFunction` as it is, it will never finish, so the `join` will block.

**End Edit**

---

Though this code doesn't have a destructor, but perhaps it should.


2. Or the thread will try to "change some class variables" after the class has gone away.
Which is obviously bad.

It might be better to change the

```
while(true)
```

to

```
while(!finished)
```

where the finished is some kind of thread-safe flag (an e.g. `atomic`) and set it in the (currently non-existent) destructor.

Comment: @Rijin - more details added as requested. I suspect you just need to decide a way to tell you polling function to stop.

Comment: Ok,I think my basics are not good.So let me clarify.. 

So, if destructor is called on any class (obj), and some other method in the class is currently under execution, both execution happens simultaneously in its own calling thread without caring about other until one of them tries to access a resource with is already unallocated, which will create an exception/core dump...Is that correct?

Comment: @Rijin Put simply, yes.